# How to compile C program with threads in gcc?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

What option do I need to use with gcc in order to get rid of errors ?

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: If you can edit your question to include things like .. what you're compiling, what errors you receive, what platform you use and what flags you pass to the compiler .. I'll be happy to evaluate this question again.

Answer (score 15):

On Linux, you should first compile with

```
gcc -g -Wall -pthread yourcode.c -lpthread -o yourprogram
```

<sup>`-g` asks for debug information, `-Wall` asks for all warnings, `-pthread` asks for POSIX threads support.</sup>

when it compiles without warnings and you have debugged it with `gdb` you might want the compiler to optimize by replacing (or adding after) `-g` with`-O2`

Very soon, you'll want to make your program made of several compilation units (linked together). You then need to learn how to use a builder like GNU [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and you'll have a `Makefile` (don't forget that tabs are significant inside them).

Of course, you should use a version control system (I suggest to use [git](http://git-scm.com), perhaps thru [gitorious](http://gitorious.org) or [github](http://github.com)) on your source code.

Comment: what Wall really does?