# double free or corruption (!prev) pthread

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm having issues while implementing a multithread program. 
The program seems to work fine for a single thread (when I set THREADS to 1) but for NTHREADS > 1, I'm getting the following error:
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

or

`double free or corruption (!prev)`

or

`free(): invalid size: 0xb6b00a10 ***
0Aborted (core dumped)`

as you can see the error varies a lot and I'm getting confused.

The program I'm executing is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NTHREADS 5
typedef struct data_t
{
    int num;
    FILE *fp;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    int thread_id;
}data_t;

void writefp(int num1, FILE *fp){
    if(fp!=NULL){
        int i;
        int nume = 1;
        int long_var=log10(nume);
        for(i=long_var;i>=0;i--){
            nume=(num1 / (int) round(pow(10, i)) % 10);
            char d=nume+'0';
            fwrite(&d, 1, 1, fp);
            printf("%c", d);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void *thread_writefp(void* args)
{
    data_t *data = (data_t *)args;
    printf(" Thread id %d\n", data->thread_id);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(data->mutex));
    writefp(data->num, data->fp);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(data->mutex));
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int randomf(){
    int num,i;
    for(i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        num = rand()%100000+1;
    }
    return num;
}

int prime(int num1){
    int is_prime=1;
    int i = 2;
    printf("Number: ");
    while( i<=num1/2 && is_prime==1 ) {
        printf("%i ", i);
        if(i%30==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        if( num1 % i == 0 ) {
                is_prime = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    if(is_prime){
            printf("%i is number prime\n", num1);
    }else{
             printf("NO is prime %i\n",num1);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(void){
    int i;
    //int num1=randomf();
    srand(time(NULL));
    FILE *fp = fopen("fich.txt", "w+b");

    data_t data;
    pthread_t consumers_thread[NTHREADS];
    data.mutex = (pthread_mutex_t) PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    data.fp = fp;

    //writefp( num1, fp);
    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
    {
        data.num = randomf();
        data.thread_id = i;
        printf("Number prime is %i\n", prime(data.num));
        if(pthread_create(&consumers_thread[i], NULL, 
                    thread_writefp, (void*) &data) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error creating thread!");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    // wait for all consumers thread to finish
    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(consumers_thread[i], NULL);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile the program as follows :

```
$gcc -pthread -Wall -o consummer consummer.c -lm
```

Here are for exemple tree error I got when I ran it with `gdb` tree successive time without changing anything to the code:

## 1

```
Thread 2 "consummer" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb7cc1b40 (LWP 18122)]
tcache_thread_freeres () at malloc.c:3003
3003    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  tcache_thread_freeres () at malloc.c:3003
#1  0xb7e258c2 in __libc_thread_freeres () at thread-freeres.c:29
#2  0xb7ea03ad in start_thread (arg=0xb7cc1b40) at pthread_create.c:478
#3  0xb7dbb0a6 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:108
(gdb)
```

## 2

```
Thread 3 "consummer" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb72ffb40 (LWP 18131)]
0xb7d2af2b in __GI__IO_fwrite (buf=0xb72ff30f, size=1, count=1, fp=0x404160) at iofwrite.c:37
37  iofwrite.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) run
```

## 3

```
Thread 3 "consummer" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0xb74c0b40 (LWP 18143)]
0xb7fd7cf9 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7fd7cf9 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7cf17e2 in __libc_signal_restore_set (set=0xb74bfe9c) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nptl-signals.h:80
#2  __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:48
#3  0xb7cf2f51 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#4  0xb7d340cc in __libc_message (action=(do_abort | do_backtrace), fmt=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#5  0xb7d3af5d in malloc_printerr (action=<optimized out>, str=0xb7e418d8 "double free or corruption (!prev)", ptr=<optimized out>, 
ar_ptr=0xb7e967a0 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:5425
#6  0xb7d3bb3b in _int_free (av=0xb7e967a0 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=have_lock@entry=0) at malloc.c:4174
#7  0xb7d3fcb0 in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x404160) at malloc.c:3144
#8  0xb7e2587d in tcache_thread_freeres () at malloc.c:3004
#9  0xb7e258c2 in __libc_thread_freeres () at thread-freeres.c:29
#10 0xb7ea03ad in start_thread (arg=0xb74c0b40) at pthread_create.c:478
#11 0xb7dbb0a6 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:108
(gdb)
```

I'd like/apreciate your help to know what I did wrong please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you understand that all your threads use the same instance of `data` variable, so all your threads are getting exactly the same values?

Comment: Would you please remove parts of your code until you get down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Unrelated to your question (still) but your `randomf` function *still* doesn't get better or more random because of the loop. The loop is pretty much useless.

Comment: @IlyaBursov good catch - and that means multiple threads are trying to access the same `FILE *fp` simultaneously = [boom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26566336/2877364)  (**Edit** I suspect the mutex doesn't help, because, from one thread's point of view, the state is changing without its notice.  However, I do not know enough about stdio implementation to be sure.)

Comment: jhonnie, please also [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48349829/edit) to show the command lines you are using to compile and run your program.  For multithreading, you may need compiler options ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813106/2877364)).  **Edit** Also, which OS?

Comment: Don't think you want to `fclose()` in your `writefp` thread while others are using it either, considering they are all sharing the same fp.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I don't think its a problem if a close the file there, as no other thread can enter that critical region when another is in it.

Comment: @IlyaBursov and @ cxw you are right, the error disappeared when I open the file in the thread function instead of doing it in the main. Thanks a lot every one for your help

Comment: Ok, so you are opening and closing the file for each thread instead of opening it once and closing it once outside the thread.  hmm.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The OP didn't ask about speed :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I followed your suggestion and it works fine too. Thanks

Comment: @cxw, the standard specifies that all the stdio stream I/O function are thread-safe on a per-call basis.  It may not work as intended when multiple threads use the same stream, but changes to stream state will definitely be noticed by all threads.

Comment: regarding: `num = rand()%100000+1;`  Due to operator precedence in C, this will not do what you are expecting.  Suggest: `num = ( rand() % 100000 ) +1;`  Notice the new parens

Comment: regarding: `FILE *fp = fopen("fich.txt", "w+b");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` to output both the enclosed text and the reason the system thinks the call failed.

Comment: regarding: `$gcc -pthread -Wall -o consummer consummer.c -lm`  1) the linker scans left to right, so the library `-pthread` should be on the right end of the command line.  2) always enable the warnings.  Suggest: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 consummer.c -o consummer -lm -pthread`

Comment: regarding: `int long_var=log10(nume);`  the function: `log10()`   this is the syntax: `double log10(double x);`  Notice it returns a `double`, not a `int`.  Suggest: `int long_var = (int)log10( (double)nume );` which, amongst other things, avoids the implicit conversions

Comment: regarding: `data.num = randomf();
        data.thread_id = i;`  There is no guarantee as to when the thread will access these values.  So there is no guarantee as to what each thread will be using for values.  This is a major logic error in the code

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error creating thread!");`   This does not output the reason the call to `pthread_create()` failed.  Suggest replacing with: `perror( "pthread_create failed" );`

Comment: regarding: `pthread_t consumers_thread[NTHREADS];` and this code block: `for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i)` Any call to `pthread_create()` that fails will result in calling `pthread_join(consumers_thread[i], NULL)` with an invalid threadID.  Suggest: `pthread_t consumers_thread[NTHREADS] = 0;` and checking for !=0 before calling `pthread_join(consumers_thread[i], NULL)`

Comment: the function: `randomf()` accomplishes nothing,  Suggest 1) remove that function.  2) replace all calls to that function with: `(rand()%100000)+1`

Comment: best programming practice is to limit the scope of variables as much as possible.  So the variable `i` currently has function scope in `main()`  That should be limited by 1) eliminate the declaration: `int i;`  2) replace: `for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )` with `for( int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++ )`  3) replace: `for( i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i )`  with `for( int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i )`

Comment: regarding all instances of: `printf("\n");`   The function: `printf()` is expensive in CPU cycles,  Suggest replacing with: `puts("");`

Comment: regarding; `        printf("%i ", i);

        if(i%30==0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }`  this adds nothing to the value of the code, except for debugging.

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(&d, 1, 1, fp);`  always compare the returned value to the 3rd parameter assure the operation was successful.  Suggest:  `if( 1 != fwrite(&d, 1, 1, fp) ) { perror("fwrite failed" ); }`

Comment: regarding: `nume = (num1 / (int) round(pow(10, i)) % 10)`:  `i` is an integer, (I.E. 1, 2, 3, 4, ...)  so the `pow()` will result in `10, 20, 30, 40, ...`  the modulo 10 will always result in 0.  calling `round()` on 0 results in 0.  Any number divided by 0 results in a  fault event.

Comment: regarding: `int long_var = (int)log10( (double)nume);`  the value passed to `log10()` is 1.0`  so the result is +0  so the value in `long_var` will always be 0.  Therefore, this code block: `for( i=long_var; i>=0; i-- )` will always be executed exactly once.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: regarding: `int i = 2;` and `while( i <= num1/2 && is_prime==1 )` and `i++;`. Suggest using the `for()` statement, then this all boils down to: `for( int i=2; i <= num1/2; i++ )
    {
        if( num1 % i == 0 )
        {
            is_prime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26566336/2877364) (**but see Edit 2**), multiple threads cannot safely access the same `FILE *fp`.  As @IlyaBursov pointed out, you only have one `data_t data` shared across all threads — and, therefore, only one `FILE *` `data.fp`.

Thanks for [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349829/double-free-or-corruption-prev-pthread#comment83686655_48349829) noting that you moved the `fopen` into the thread function.  That way each thread independently opens and closes the file, so there is no `FILE *` sharing between threads.

This seems to be implementation-dependent — I was not able to reproduce the issue on Cygwin x64 with gcc 6.4.0.  I suspect the effect of the mutex may also vary by implementation.  It may also be dependent on compiler options — see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813106/2877364).

**Edit** As @MichaelDorgan pointed out, calling `fclose` on a `FILE *` that other threads are using is also a bad idea.

**Edit 2** As @JohnBollinger points out, [individual stream operations are thread-safe](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Threads.html#Streams-and-Threads) these days.  That would suggest that the `fclose` before another thread tried to access the file might be the problem.  However, I wonder if perhaps the OP's stdio implementation is non-conformant in some way.  I would think a [compliant `fwrite`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Block-Input_002fOutput.html#Block-Input_002fOutput) would simply return error on an access to a closed file, rather than crashing.  *See further comments below.*

Comment: Sorry, the other answer you cite is just wrong, at least with respect to the current standard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Would you please point me to the correction?  Then I will edit the answer.  **Edit** I just saw your other comment - is "the same stream" defined by "the same `FILE *`" in the current standard, or some other way?  Thanks!

Comment: We have "[a `FILE`] is an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a stream" (C2011, [7.21.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p2)) and "The address of the FILE object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a FILE object need not serve in place of the original" (C2011 [7.21.3/6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p6)), and a few others in their vicinity.  That's not as explicit as one might hope, but there's no workable interpretation that does not effectively make the locking requirement apply to `FILE`s.

Comment: With regard to your Edit 2, I am confident that one thread attempting to write to the file after another has closed it is at least *a* serious problem with the OP's code.  It is plausibly sufficient by itself to explain the errors the OP reported.